running validator is not discovered by others. Inbound connections: null
Node is alive I can telnet it, it is Synced in TestNet and paricipates in SCP but it can't be discovered by other nodes. Inbound connections: null. what to look for? when Node realizes its IP? what is happening when Node starts running? some hello messages no the network?
tnx in advance for help!
